# Wordpress Shortcode WYSIWYG

Tags: editor, wysiwyg, execute, shortcode

I'am looking for a simple code with which I could "execute" the shortcode on fly in the wordpress content editor. Let's say I have a column shortcode [one_third]. With putting some content in it ( [one_third]some long content..[/one_third] the shortcode will appear in my page as a columns that takes one third of the page content area.

How would I implement the code so that if I create a page(Sample page) and write some text into the content. Then I would want to select all the text, click on one_third button(the buttons should be put above the editor - got ideas how to do that). As a result I would want to have the shortcode not written in the content editor but already executed. So that for the above example I would get something like this:

[image]

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can do this, as shortcodes are only processed when the post/page is being viewed. Shortcodes are not generated/processed during editing.

However you can write a WordPress plugin to extend the capabilities of the WYSIWYG editor, such as a button to insert a HTML template into the WYSIWYG editor, and generating the 1/3 view as you would like to see.

Comment: Hi, tnx for the answer. can you be more specific on how that would be coded? Would this effect the outcome on the page then? Because that works ok, just need to get the backend content view (editor) to "somehow" display as it the shortcode was executed.